# Alternative for creating Loopback REST Object?

Tags: android, rest, object, loopbackjs

Is there any other way to create an Object for the Loopback repository other than below mentioned way?

```
obj = Repository.createObject(ImmutableMap.of("key","value"));
obj.key2 = "value2";
```